# PL/pgPSM installation issue

Tags: database, postgresql

I have been trying to install PL/pgPSM in postgres without much success. I tried installing PL/pgPSM by following the instructions at the bottom of this page http://postgres.cz/wiki/SQL/PSM_Manual but the make file just tells me.

```
Makefile:18: ../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:19: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

When I try to issue:

```
make USE PGXS=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have not installed the devel packages for PostgreSQL.

I am also not sure to what extent PSM is compilable on newest Postgres version. [**PSM0**](https://github.com/okbob/plpsm0) is more modern and significantly more correct.

You should know that both implementations are highly experimental and not supported as of now. I am working on a reimplementation of PSM0, but I am a relative far from production usage.
I welcome any `PL/pgPSM` users! :)